# Similar to Facebook's Status/Share Widget with people and place taging in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Is there any open source similar to Facebook's share/status update widget or I have made my own. I already searched but found only simple friend selections (auto-complete, like we have in Facebook compose message).

Any Idea to implement will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to code your own but you can keep what key assets are used to solve the problem. From my prospective!

You need to take a look at

- Type-head for person & places i.e try FCBK auto sugguest
- Editable content
- Temporary version of post, before the user post it
- Uploading of images/ videos via ajax or with some chunk data passing
- Url meta data reading